# ReferenceError: require is not defined using webpack for VScode extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, webpack

I'm pretty new to JS, TS and Node, but have a strong background in other languages such as Golang and Python.. so don't hold back on me.

I'm creating a VS code extension, using Webpack & TypeScript. My understanding is Webpack should allow me to use TS and JS interchangeably, which is the goal.

I've got a project layout like so:

````
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── README.md
├── dist
│   ├── extension.js
│   └── extension.js.map
├── node_modules  [244 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
├── out
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── auth.js
│   │   └── auth.js.map
│   ├── extension.js
│   ├── extension.js.map
│   ├── media
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   └── main.js.map
│   ├── providers
│   │   ├── MyViewProvider.js
│   │   └── MyViewProvider.js.map
│   └── test
│       ├── extension.test.js
│       └── extension.test.js.map
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── auth
│   │   └── auth.ts
│   ├── extension.ts
│   ├── media
│   │   ├── main.css
│   │   ├── main.ts
│   │   ├── reset.css
│   │   └── vscode.css
│   ├── providers
│   │   └── MyViewProvider.ts
│   └── test
│       └── extension.test.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── vsc-extension-quickstart.md
└── webpack.config.js```
````

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "Node16",
        "target": "ES2022",
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "ES2022"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true   /* enable all strict type-checking options */
        /* Additional Checks */
        // "noImplicitReturns": true, /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
//@ts-check

'use strict';

const path = require('path');

//@ts-check
/** @typedef {import('webpack').Configuration} WebpackConfig **/

/** @type WebpackConfig */
const extensionConfig = {
  target: 'web', // VS Code extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/
    mode: 'development', // this leaves the source code as close as possible to the original (when packaging we set this to 'production')

  entry: './src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
  output: {
    // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'extension.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  externals: {
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    // modules added here also need to be added in the .vscodeignore file
  },
  resolve: {
    // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: "log", // enables logging required for problem matchers
  },
};
module.exports = [ extensionConfig ];
```

The problem I am seeing seems to come from extension.ts, in which I run: `import * as vscode from 'vscode';`, this compiles fine when I do `npm run compile` but once I run this extension in VScode in the development host, it throws an error in the developer log for `'ReferenceError: require is not defined'`

The goal here is that extension.js imports the provider class from MyViewProvider.ts, and this class contains the HTML and whatnot, for the webview. Within that HTML, I load a script which links to src/auth/auth.ts.

But I can't proceed until I figure out whats going on with the VScode import

Any ideas?

Comment: Setting `"module": "Node16"` in your tsconfig is going to compile your `import` statements to `require` calls, and the code running your code is apparently using ES modules. Change your module format output to one of the ESM options like `esnext`. And don't feel bad about being confused coming from other languages, Javascript is somewhat unique in that it has two different only semi-compatible module systems for complicated historical reasons and interop issues are a thorn in the side of many a JS/TS dev.

Comment: Arguably a duplicate, but it's just different enough that I don't want to use Mjolnir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/browser-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: @JaredSmith I've set the "module" to a value of "esnext", and I am still seeing the same error unfortunately..

Comment: That's weird. I'm wondering if webpack is the issue. I'm also wondering why you're using webpack at all, because you aren't targeting a browser. The Typescript compiler should be sufficient... can you share a little more detail here? Also, did you use the [official extension project scaffolding](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension)? Sorry I'm a vimmer and don't use vscode, but that was the top hit on Google search.

Comment: @JaredSmith it could be webpack, for sure. But I've actually followed the official starter doc to create a webpack and non webpack version, and I am seeing the same error for both.. I'd happily try to debug the non webpack version if you think its more suitable in this scenario.

Comment: I do, webpack is a very flexible tool, with all of the good and bad that adjective implies.